# Is a text file bigger on Windows than on Linux because of carriage return?

Tags: linux, windows, newlines, size, line

Let's say I have the same ASCII text file on Linux and Windows:

```
one
two
three
```

The two files will have `\n` and `\r\n` respectively as EOL character on the two OSes.

Does this mean that the file on Linux is smaller?

This test, performed on linux, seems say yes:

```
$ echo -en 'one\ntwo\nthree\n' | wc --bytes 
14
$ echo -en 'one\r\ntwo\r\nthree\r\n' | wc --bytes 
17
```

Comment: CR \r is a real character and occupies one byte.

Comment: So my test I've just added is relevant and gives the correct result, doesn't it?

Comment: Strictly, no. You ran two different echo commands on Linux, and compared those. That says nothing about Windows. You would need to FTP the file to Windows in ascii mode, find the exact size there, and verify the text is unchanged. It used to be true on DOS (and is still apparently true in Windows) that MS stores a hard EOF character Ctrl-Z (Hex 1A, "SUB") inside text files, and will not read past that even if further text is present. See `https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/yeby3zcb(v=vs.140)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your test is correct, albeit strictly speaking limited — it only shows that on Linux, the strings produced by your `echo` commands occupy respectively 14 and 17 bytes as measured by `wc --bytes`. Each `\n` and `\r` occupy one byte, so each newline incurs a one-byte penalty when using DOS/Windows-style newlines.

Strictly speaking, the storage requirements depend on the program you use to write the file; neither Linux nor Windows impose anything on the contents of the file. It is possible to store files with CRLF newlines on Linux, and files with LF newlines on Windows. To determine the storage requirements of your file on either operating system, you should write it using whatever tool you aim to use, on both operating systems, and measure the file’s size using the operating system’s tools.

Note that files typically use storage in multiples of a certain unit of storage, so the variation related to newlines might not have a practical impact.

Comment: The test is incomplete, as it demonstrates nothing about how the file is truly stored on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe.

Windows is perfectly capable of storing any binary files, without any special processing of the CR and LF characters -- otherwise no binary file format would work. But it is customary for Windows programs to store newlines as CR+LF pairs, unlike on Unixen where the custom is to just use LF. That custom may be codified in the system libraries, too, but I haven't touched Windows programming in ages, so I'm not one to say.

However, that's not all... If you open even just Notepad and start saving a file, you'll be faced with some options on the format. On the system I had at hand, the choices were "ANSI", "Unicode" and "UTF-8". I created a file with the content `foo⏎bar⏎doo⏎` (where `⏎` is a newline), and the resulting file sizes were 15, 32 and 18 bytes, respectively.

That first one is simply `foo\r\nbar\r\ndoo\r\n`, stored in the Windows-1252 codepage, though it doesn't matter with these characters. An `ä` would be stored here as one byte. The second is UTF-16 (or UCS-2?), so two bytes per character, plus a two-byte byte-order mark (BOM). The characters include CR and LF, so it's 15 characters plus the BOM for 32 bytes in total. The third one, UTF-8, is the same as the first, except with the UTF-8 encoded BOM prefixing the text, adding three bytes. In UTF-8, an `ä` is two characters. Well, after writing that, I notice you mentioned "ASCII text file", but the differences between encodings show that the applications can write whatever they want in the file.

I'd expect that if I were to take e.g. Cygwin's Bash under Windows, and run `echo -e 'foo\nbar\ndoo\n'`, I would get those 12 bytes only, no CR bytes. In the same way, any text editor on Windows could store files with just LF for a newline.

So, really, it depends on what program you use to create the file and what format you ask it to save the file in.